# Problem adding a Site Script and Site Design

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, spfx

We are looking at Site Designs for some things we want to do like Content Types, set theme, site columns, and I'm trying to add a really simple Site Scrip but I'm getting the following error.  So I haven't been successful and cannot find help on how to troubleshoot this.

```
Add-SPOSiteScript : Nous n’avons pas pu traiter l’action setTitle. Le gestionnaire d’actions n’est pas inscrit pour cette action.
Au caractère C:\siteTest\test-SiteScript.ps1:14 : 36
+ ... File -Raw | Add-SPOSiteScript -Title $siteScriptTitle -Description $s ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-SPOSiteScript], ServerException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException,Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell.AddSPOSiteScript
```

Here is my PowerShell Script

```
$adminSiteUrl = "https://my0365-admin.sharepoint.com"
$siteScriptFile = $PSScriptRoot + "\test-SiteDesign.json"
$webTemplate = "68" #64 = Team Site, 68 = Communication Site

$siteScriptTitle = "TEST Site design script"
$siteDesignTitle = "TEST Site design script"
$siteDesignDescription = "Site design ."

$cred = Get-Credential

Connect-SPOService $adminSiteUrl -Credential $cred

Get-Content $siteScriptFile -Raw | Add-SPOSiteScript -Title $siteScriptTitle -Description $siteDesignDescription
```

And my Design

```
{
    "$schema": "schema.json",
    "actions": [
        {
            "verb": "setTitle",
            "title": "Titre du site"
         }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTitle` is a subAction. It needs to be inside the `createSPList` action.

Modify your JSON as below and then run your code it should work:

```
{
    "$schema": "schema.json",
    "actions": [
        {
            "verb": "createSPList",
            "listName": "Custom List",
            "templateType": 100,
            "subactions": [
                {
                   "verb": "setTitle",
                   "title": "Customers and Orders"
                }               
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Reference - [Site Design JSON Schema](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-json-schema)

Comment: Yeah I figured that out late yeasterday evening.  I misunderstood this.  Thanks.

Comment: cool, you can [accept it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by ticking the checkmark besides the answer. It will remove this from list of unanswered questions and help other users who might face similar issue. Cheers ! :)